# Explaining Characteristics of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE:
$$y\cdot u_x+x\cdot u_y=0$$
I'm trying to find out what the characteristics of this PDE are. Now I know the characteristic equation is given by:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{y}$$
So are the Characteristics the parabolas that have $x=y$ and $x=-y$ as asymptotes along with the lines $x=y$ and $x=-y$ themselves, or am I missing some Characteristics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of characteristics consists in setting $u(x,y) = u(x(s),y(s))$, and transform the PDE in $(x,y)$ into an ODE in $s$. Here,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}s} = x'\, u_x + y'\, u_y \, .
$$
We set the equations of characteristics
$$
x' = 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad y' = \frac{x}{y}\, ,
$$
such that $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}s = 0$, i.e. $u$ is constant along the characteristics.
Thus, $$ \frac{y'}{x'} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{x}{y} \, , $$ which solutions are $y^2 = x^2 + C$, with constant $C$. The value of $u$ is completely determined by the constant $C$, so that the solutions of the PDE are
$$
u(x,y) = f(y^2 - x^2)\, ,
$$
where $f$ is any differentiable function. To go further, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423439/solving-the-pde-y-u-x-x-u-y-1-u0-y-e-y2) is related.

Comment: Thanks! I'm mostly looking for a word description or a way to describe what each characteristic looks like however @Harry49

Comment: The curves of the form $y^2-x^2=C$ are known as [hyperbolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola), @FelicioGrande

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. But these hyperbolas do not intersect the lines $x=y$ and $x=-y$, correct? Unless of course the 2 cases $x=y$ and $x=-y$. @Michelle

Comment: @FelicioGrande Right, the case $C=0$ is exceptional; we get two lines, which is kind of a degenerate hyperbola.