# Trouble understanding solution to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I was looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423439/solving-the-pde-y-u-x-x-u-y-1-u0-y-e-y2), and I think I understand how most of the solution goes, but there's one line that's still pretty mysterious to me.

Under the second method that's presented, using characteristic curves, we see the implication $$y dy- x dx = 0 \implies d(y^2-x^2) = 0.$$

I was hoping someone could shed some light on 1) how this move is justified, and 2) why what the motivation is for taking this step?

Comment: $d(y^2-x^2)=2ydy-2xdx$

Comment: Wow. That was way more straightforward than I thought.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: are you familiar with [exact differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential#Two_and_three_dimensions)?

Comment: Not really, no. I'm kind of learning on the fly, and so had assumed than much of the algebra being done with things of the form $du$ was justified through taking limits and linearity of the differential operator.